# In Winforms, can I configure the combobox to allow values not in the drop down list?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox that displays a list of 'active' objects the user can select from. However, if the user goes into some older data screens, the selected values of some of the comboboxes might be old and 'inactive' objects that aren't in the current list.

I want the combobox to just display the old value even though it is not in the list. And I don't want the user to be able to manually edit it either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Isaac

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that it's your code that is removing the objects from the ComboBox in the first place, so you just... don't do that.  To disallow typing into the ComboBox set its DropDownStyle property to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList.

Comment: no, it's not like that. I'm getting the active objects from a database. My ORM is filtering the inactive ones out.

Comment: Well, right now I'm leaning towards automatically adding the combo box value not in the list to be in the list in my combobox class that inherits from the original combobox. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Ahh, ok then.  I'm probably not the best guy to give advice on object relational databases and UI's :D